# wrong URL for Authentication docker image

Tags: docker, taiga

Hopefully someone has an experience with this application. I am following the docs here https://resources.taiga.io/30min-setup/

A strange thing that happens is when I try to LogIn to this application and check the URL that the request is being sent to..I see this.

[image: Double URL]

Could this be because of My Mistake?

I have deployed this docker container on an Azure Windows VM

I am not shraing the `docker-compose` because I do not know if I should. This looks like a mistake in the front-end code. I can share `docker-compose` if it is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the url in the documentation I cloned the repository from here `https://github.com/taigaio/taiga-docker` and it works.